# How can I prevent a CA7 job with two schedule IDs from conflicting when they run on the same day?

Tags: websphere, job-scheduling, mainframe

I have a single job with two schedule ID’s. One runs the job the last day of the month and the other schid runs the last Sunday of the month. The problem I’m trying to correct arises when the last day of the month falls on a Sunday which causes a conflict between the two schedules.

My first thought was to split the two schids into two separate job names, while making one job a requirement for the other so they can’t run at the same time. The problem is this scenario would only apply on the rare days they both run and on all other days the requirement wouldn’t be met.

I’m not extremely familiar with ca7 so thought I’d look for some input. Can a schid be created with a conditional statement?

Comment: So do you actually want the job to run on both the last day of the month and also the last Sunday of the month? If the last day of the month is a Sunday, do you want it to run twice? Can you post details of the conflict you are getting and the outcome of that conflict? (Job doesn't run at all, CA-7 crashes, z/OS crashes, the mainframe goes into a disabled wait-state etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think two schids will be needed.  The options assume a calendar that specifies all days as processing days.

**Option 1**

Schid=1 schedules the job on the last Sunday of the month UNLESS that Sunday falls on the last day of the month.

Schid=2 schedules the job on the last day of the month.

```
   ID=001   ROLL=N  INDEX=+000
   SCAL=    DOTM=2000  LEADTM=0010  STARTM=1950
            MONTHLY   DAY=SUN  WEEK=-00  MONTH=ALL
            MONTHLY  NRDAY=-00  MONTH=ALL
   ID=002   ROLL=N  INDEX=+000
   SCAL=    DOTM=2000  LEADTM=0010  STARTM=1950
            MONTHLY   RDAY=-00  MONTH=ALL
```

**Option 2**

Schid=1 runs the last day of the month unless that day falls on a Sunday.

Schid=2 runs on the last Sunday of the month.

```
   ID=001   ROLL=D  INDEX=+000
   SCAL=    DOTM=1300  LEADTM=0030  STARTM=1230
            MONTHLY  NDAY=SUN  WEEK=-00  MONTH=ALL
            MONTHLY   RDAY=-00  MONTH=ALL
   ID=002   ROLL=D  INDEX=+000
   SCAL=    DOTM=1300  LEADTM=0030  STARTM=1230
            MONTHLY   DAY=SUN  WEEK=-00  MONTH=ALL
```

Another approach is to define a separate calendar with precisely the days I want the job to run so the schedule definition is pretty simple.